# Toggle between two ngClass classes on click, but only for clicked element

Tags: css, angular, angular5

I have a list of items generated with a `*ngFor` loop. I want these elements to toggle between two classes on click, but obviously I only want the clicked element to toggle the class.

HTML:

```
<div class="closed" (click)="clickEvent($event)" [ngClass]="{'open': toggle}"></div>
```

component.ts:

```
clickEvent(event) {
    private toggle : boolean = false;
    clickEvent(event) {
      this.toggle != this.toggle;
    }
  }
```

With the above setup, the initial class (`.closed`) is applied, but when I click on an element the `.open` class is not applied, and clicking on the element again does not re-display the `.closed` class.

Answer (score 0):

Use an id to help you. Like this:

```
<div class="closed" onClick="change()" id="btn"></div>
```

(javascript)

```
var change = false;
function change(){
  if(!change){
    document.getElementById("btn").className = "open";
    change = true;    
 }else{
    document.getElementyById("btn").className = "closed";
    change = false;
 }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but because the elements are accordions generated through Angular, they already have an id based on their index.

Comment: Sry then. i can't help you

Answer (score 0):

Ive created a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wc4dda, it does what you need but you are going to have to add additional data to the list. If you click on the items in the example it hides the content on the list item based by swapping out the open and closed classes.